# 「持参の上」の「上」の意味は何ですか。

Tags: words

下の文章で「上」の意味は何ですか。

例）「このはがき持参の上、おいでください。」

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「このはがきを持参し、おいでください」という意味です

> ６ ある事柄と他の事柄とを関係させていう時に用いる。
>   ㋑…したのち。…した結果。「相談した上で返事する」「知的探検家の努力の上に現代科学は築かれている」 -- https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/17464/meaning/m0u/

Comment: 「何かすでにした行為の上に積み重ねる」イメージで考えるとわかりやすいと思います。例文でいうと「はがきを持ってくる」というベースがあり、その上に「来る」という行為を積み重ねるイメージです。